# whats with Chinese and Russian proxy servers?

Tags: network, server, internet

I keep hearing that if you commit some network activity via Chinese or Russian proxy servers you are very difficult to be tracked down.

What is the reason for this other than lack of international Co-operation?

If the servers obey cyber laws they should have logs of all data with its origin and destination.  So an enquiry would ultimately result in a 100% accurate track down if all agencies operate lawfully and co-operate.

so what is the reason for activity being untraceable?

Comment: "obey cyber laws" - whose cyber laws?

Comment: If you remove the factor of politics and think in 100% technical scenario, then is there any way to still hide your activity?

Comment: Any server can technically drop all records of data passing through it - it's not illegal usually. Servers that don't do this usually do it from a legal or political reason, rather than a technical one.

Comment: @Matthew so why not all ISP/Proxy servers that don't keep records used for illegal activity?

Comment: They probably _are_ used for illegal activity, but you can't tell. There are legitimate reasons not to keep logs too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get information from most providers in China and Russia you need their equivalent of a subpoena. Both Russian and Chinese courts are not known to be very willing in giving these out to foreign governments or businesses.